# Custom navigation bar minimum font scale?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, customization, title

I need to set a minimum font scale on my navigation bar. I set title attributes in my AppDelegate.m:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:54/255.0f green:54/255.0f blue:54/255.0f alpha:1.0f],
                     UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 0.0f)],
                                 UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.0f]
 }];
```

My navigation bar is dragged and dropped on a UIView in my storyboard. Everything works fine with cusom navigation bar image and the text attributes, except I need to set the minimum font scale if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating a label and use as navigation bar title.

```
// NavBar title
UILabel *customNavBarTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 320, 44)];
customNavBarTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
customNavBarTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[customNavBarTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:15.0f]];
[customNavBarTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[customNavBarTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor];
[customNavBarTitle setText:customTitle];
[self.view addSubview:customNavBarTitle];
```